# Помогите убрать белый квадрат Python Pil

Tags: python, изображения, pil, pillow

Вообщем цитату отправляет но с белым квадратом в углу. Я не понимаю откуда он берется помогите пожалуйста.

```
from handler.base_plugin import CommandPlugin
from utils import upload_photo
from utils import traverse, timestamp_to_date

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps

import aiohttp, io


class QuoteDoerPlugin(CommandPlugin):
    __slots__ = ("q", "qf", "f", "fs", "fss")

    def __init__(self, *commands, prefixes=None, strict=False):
        """Answers with image containing stylish quote."""

        if not commands:
            commands = ("цитата",)

        super().__init__(*commands, prefixes=prefixes, strict=strict)

        self.q = Image.open(self.get_path("q.png")).resize((40, 40), Image.LANCZOS)
        self.qf = self.q.copy().transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)

        self.f = ImageFont.truetype(self.get_path("font.ttf"), 24)
        self.fs = ImageFont.truetype(self.get_path("font.ttf"), 16)
        self.fss = ImageFont.truetype(self.get_path("font.ttf"), 15)

        example = self.command_example()
        self.description = [f" {example} [титул] - перешлите сообщение и укажите титул (по желанию) и "
                             "получите цитату!"]

    def make_image(self, img, text, name, last_name, timestamp, otext):
        rsize = (700, 400)

        res = Image.open(self.get_path("/default.jpg")).convert('RGBA')
        res.paste(img, (25, 100))

        tex = Image.new("RGBA", (rsize), (0, 0, 0, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(tex)

        if len(text) > 70:
            font = self.fss
        else:
            font = self.f

        sidth = int(draw.textsize(" ", font=font)[0])

        width, height = 0, 0
        new_text = ""

        for line in text.splitlines():
            for word in line.split():
                word_width = len(word) * sidth

                if width + word_width >= rsize[0] - 340:
                    width = 0
                    new_text += "\n"

                width += sidth + word_width
                new_text += word + " "

            width = 0
            new_text += "\n"

        new_text = new_text[:-1]

        width, height = draw.multiline_textsize(new_text, font=font)
        draw.multiline_text((0, 0), new_text, font=font)

        y = rsize[1] // 2 - height // 2
        x = 300 + (rsize[0] - 370 - width) // 2

        res.paste(tex, (x, y))

        if y <= 10:
            return "Не получилось... простите."

        if height < 210:
            height = 210
            y = rsize[1] // 2 - height // 2

        res.paste(self.q, (240, y))
        res.paste(self.qf, (rsize[0] - 65, y + height - 40))

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(res)
        draw.multiline_text((25, 310), f"© {name} {last_name}{' - ' + otext if otext else ''}"
            f"\n@ {timestamp_to_date(timestamp)}", font=self.fs)

        buff = io.BytesIO()
        res.save(buff, format='png')

        return buff.getvalue()

    async def process_message(self, msg):
        command, otext = self.parse_message(msg)

        i, url, name, last_name, timestamp = None, None, None, None, None

        for m in traverse(await msg.get_full_forwarded()):
            if m.full_text:
                if i == m.true_user_id:
                    text += "\n" + m.full_text
                    continue
                elif i is not None:
                    break

                i = m.true_user_id
                timestamp = m.timestamp

                u = await self.api.users.get(user_ids=i, fields="photo_max")
                if not u:
                    continue

                u = u[0]

                url = u["photo_max"]
                name = u["first_name"]
                last_name = u["last_name"]

                text = m.full_text
        else:
            if i is None:
                return await msg.answer("Нечего цитировать!")

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sess:
            async with sess.get(url) as response:
                img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(await response.read())).convert('RGBA')
                img = img.resize((200, 200))
                ll_size = (1000, 100,)
                mask = Image.new('L', ll_size, 0)
                draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
                draw.ellipse((0, 0) + ll_size, fill=255)

                mask = ImageOps.fit(mask, img.size, method=Image.BITCUBIC, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
                img.putalpha(mask)

        result = await self.run_in_executor(self.make_image, img, text, name, last_name, timestamp, otext)

        if isinstance(result, str):
            return await msg.answer(result)

        attachment = await upload_photo(self.api, result, msg.user_id)

        return await msg.answer(attachment=str(attachment))
```

Скриншот который выводит:
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Тот текст это текст, который был нарисован или вставленная картинка?

Comment: Он берет текст который написали и рисует его

Comment: и тот в `draw.multiline_text((0, 0), new_text, font=font)` нарисуется? У вас комментариев не хватает в коде. А лучше если бы был только проблемный код :)

Comment: Вставил весь код, просто это не мой код а я решил переделать что бы выводилось не черное изображение а мое)

Comment: Смотрите, у вас код поехал, т.к. форматирования нет. В редакторе есть кнопка `{}`, выделите ваш код и тыкните на нее. Даже если код не ваш, вам нужно будет в нем разобраться, а чтобы оставить только нужное достаточно убрать места, которые не рисуют тот текст. Меня смущает что текст под фоткой нормально отрисовался, а та цитата вот так безобразно

Comment: Готово, прошу прощения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясняю что происходит.

`tex = Image.new("RGBA", (rsize), (0, 0, 0, 0))` – место создания картинки с текстом (та что с сплошным фоном)

`res.paste(tex, (x, y))` – вставка картинки в общую картинку. Все что между ними находится служит только для нарисования переданного текста. А тот цикл нужен чтобы текст не вышел за пределы картинки текста.

Я подумал, что можно тот текст напрямую нарисовать на главной картинке, попутно нашел способ обойтись без цикла – модуль `textwrap`.

Код:

```
import datetime as DT
import textwrap

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def timestamp_to_date(timestamp):
    dt = DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    return dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


def make_image(img_avatar, text, name, last_name, timestamp, otext):
    res = Image.open("default.jpg").convert('RGBA')
    res.paste(img_avatar, (25, 100))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(res)

    text = textwrap.fill(text, width=35)
    footer_text = f"© {name} {last_name}{' - ' + otext if otext else ''}\n@ {timestamp_to_date(timestamp)}"

    draw.multiline_text((250, 200), text, fill="Black")
    draw.multiline_text((25, 310), footer_text, fill="Black")

    res.save('result.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_avatar = Image.open("avatar.png").convert('RGBA')
    text = """Fill a single paragraph of text, returning a new string.
        Reformat the single paragraph in 'text' to fit in lines of no more
        than 'width' columns, and return a new string containing the entire
        wrapped paragraph.  As with wrap(), tabs are expanded and other
        whitespace characters converted to space.  See TextWrapper class for
        available keyword args to customize wrapping behaviour.
    """
    name = 'Foo'
    last_name = 'Bar'
    timestamp = 1529682155
    otext = 'Bla-bla-bla'
    
    make_image(img_avatar, text, name, last_name, timestamp, otext)
```

**default.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**avatar.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** Понадобится рассчитать размер текста, чтобы цитату с правого края размещать. Т.к. `textwrap` смотрит на количество символов при разбиении текста. Понадобится немного поиграться. (`width, height = draw.multiline_textsize(new_text, font=font)` поможет)

Если не понравился вариант с `textwrap`, можно его убрать, просто сразу рисовать на исходной картинке.

Те кавычки вставляются в

```
res.paste(self.q, (240, y))
res.paste(self.qf, (rsize[0] - 65, y + height - 40))
```